# I want to let the <li> text coming from the list take a style="background-color: aqua" in the textarea after a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I add a style="background-color: aqua" as a highlight in the textarea just to the word coming from the list above after a click.
Here my html:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="box">
     <li>Add</li>
     <li>Sum</li>
     <li>Div</li>
     <li>Text4</li>
     <li>Text5</li>
</ul>
<textarea  rows="4" cols="50" id="id-of-your-textarea"></textarea>
 
</body>
```

Here my script:

```
 <script>
const textArea = document.getElementById('id-of-your-textarea');
const boxLi= document.getElementById('box').children;

for(let i = 0; i < boxLi.length; i++){
  boxLi[i].addEventListener('click', () => {    
    textArea.value +=boxLi[i].textContent;  
  })
}
  </script>
```

Comment: highlight the li or the word inside textarea?

Comment: Highlight just the li in the textarea. The others things written by me on the textarea don't be highlighted.

Comment: so you write in the textarea and highlight the li if the words are exist in textarea?

Comment: When I click to a word in the list, it appear in the textarea. I want it to appear highlighted.

Comment: You cant hilite a word in a textarea. what you should use is a div into which you add the word and wrap into in a span element. with css you could specify a hilite on the span. if you want to post the data later use a hidden textarea into which you copy innertext of the div

Comment: I've used a textarea because I want to write something in the textarea  and add a li after a click.

Answer (score 0):

The TextArea Only contains the text content so styling the textarea content is not possible, Instead, you can use a  element, and there the text you enter can be highlighted.

Try this

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <style>
    .background{
    height:100px;
    width:500px;
    border:2px solid black;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="box">
    <li>Add</li>
    <li>Sum</li>
    <li>Div</li>
    <li>Text4</li>
    <li>Text5</li>
</ul>
<div class="background" id="id-of-your-textarea" contenteditable>
 This is a Sum Add For the Text4 any random text 
</div>

</body>
<script>
const textArea = document.getElementById('id-of-your-textarea');
const boxLi= document.getElementById('box').children;

function highlighter(e)
{
  let text = e.target.textContent;
  let innerText = textArea.textContent;
  if(innerText) { 
    textArea.innerHTML = innerText.replace(text, `<span style="background-color:aqua;">${text}</span>`)
  }
}

for(list of boxLi)
  {
    list.addEventListener('click', highlighter)
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: It can't work with an empty textarea where i add text and a li from the list after a click? And just highlight the li added?